# Is it possible to set a timeout when dequeuing an item from a TensorFlow queue?

Tags: timeout, queue, tensorflow

I am building a neural network ensemble where each net reads the inputs from an input queue and writes its prediction to an output queue, and a separate client pushes a new input to all input queues then pulls the individual predictions from each output queue and aggregates them to produce the ensemble's prediction.

I would like the system to be resilient to a slow (or crashed) neural network client, so I need to set a timeout when pulling from each output queue. Ideally, the aggregator graph would behave nicely and just ignore that prediction.

The only solution I have found to have a dequeue timeout is to set the `operation_timeout_in_ms` configuration option when creating the session, but this applies to all operations in the graph (for this session). Not very granular.

Any other option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a timeout on an individual `tf.Session.run()` call, which is most useful when you have a potentially blocking operation, such as a `dequeue()`. To do this, pass an optional [`tf.RunOptions`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ad4f02a69162abe5d242b7d94f62138849aec9ab/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L226) object to the `run()` call, and set the `timeout_in_ms` field to the desired timeout in milliseconds:

```
op = ...  # Assume this depends on dequeuing a tensor from a queue.
sess = tf.Session()

# Set a 10-second timeout.
run_options = tf.RunOptions(timeout_in_ms=10000)
try:
  sess.run(op, options=run_options)
except tf.errors.DeadlineExceededError:  # This will be raised if the timeout expires.
  # ...
```